# What is the syntax for using a contrib module's service from within a hook implementation?

Tags: 8, symfony-services

I'm trying to get a list of objects from AWS using the S3fsService from the [S3 File System module](https://www.drupal.org/project/s3fs) from within a `hook_cron()` implementation. The following code works:

```
// Fetch list of files in S3.
$config = \Drupal::config('s3fs.settings')->get();
$s3 = \Drupal\s3fs\S3fsService::getAmazonS3Client($config);
$iterator_args = ['Bucket' => $config['bucket']];
$iterator = $s3->getIterator('ListObjectVersions', $iterator_args);
```

…but I'm getting a message saying `Deprecated function: Non-static method Drupal\s3fs\S3fsService::getAmazonS3Client() should not be called statically…`.

How should I be calling it differently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access services via `\Drupal::service('service.name')`.

You need to know the service's name to access it, though. Looking at the s3fs module, I can see in the module's *s3fs.services.yml* file that the class your requesting is available with the service name *s3fs*.

```
$s3fs = \Drupal::service('s3fs');
$result = $s3fs->getAmazonS3Client($config);
```